# Update Python in Laragom - Windows 7 (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip')

Tags: python, pip, windows-7

I have Laragon with Python 3.6.1 (folder: bin\python-3.6.1), work perfect, with pip.

But i need update this. So i install the Python python-3.8.6 (folder: bin\python-3.8.6), and pip dont work.
The error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

I Try

```
Run

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Then run the following command in the folder where you downloaded: get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

But dont work.

Comment: Have you checked that your PATH environment variables are set correctly?

Comment: The `pip` for Python 3.8.6 should be in `bin\python-3.8.6\Scripts`. Navigate to that folder and execute it from there.

Comment: Yes, i think that PATH is correct.

Comment: I navigate to the folder Scripts, but the pip dont work